# handling lifetypes in iterator extension

Tags: rust

I'm attempting to extend Iterator with a `group_by_count` method:

```
use itertools::Itertools;

trait ExtIterator<T>
where
    T: Sized,
{
    fn group_by_count(self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = (T, usize)>>
    where
        T: Sized;
}

impl<T: 'static, I: 'static> ExtIterator<T> for I
where
    I: Iterator<Item = T> + Sized,
    T: Clone + Eq + PartialEq + Sized,
{
    fn group_by_count(self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = (T, usize)>>
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        Box::new(
            self.group_by(|i| i.clone())
                .into_iter()
                .map(|(key, group)| (key, group.count())),
        )
    }
}
```

I'm getting:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src/ext/iterator.rs:21:9
   |
21 | /         Box::new(
22 | |             self.group_by(|i| i.clone())
   | |             ---------------------------- temporary value created here
23 | |                 .into_iter()
24 | |                 .map(|(key, group)| (key, group.count())),
25 | |         )
   | |_________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
   |
   = help: use `.collect()` to allocate the iterator
```

It doesn't feel right to call `collect` here, and clippy suggests the `collect` should be removed if I do. But I can't puzzle out how to avoid creating a temporary value.

Comment: [Clippy doesn't suggest that for me](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=05f4f930217ae42a6fe17ce1fa58cf24).

Comment: Nitpicks: `Sized` bounds are redundant (they're the default). Also `Eq` implies `PartialEq` and thus you only need `Eq`, but actually you don't need `Eq` (`group_by()` doesn't require it) and so you only need `PartialEq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that without a custom iterator adapter.

But it's easy to create a new `GroupByCount` iterator, and then, relying on the fact that multiple calls to `into_iter()` on `GroupBy` change the underlying iterator, implement its `next()` method:

```rust
pub struct GroupByCount<I: Iterator> {
    // This `fn(&K) -> K` could be `Box<dyn FnMut(&K) -> K`, but
    // this adds one usize to the struct's size, and the function
    // captures nothing.
    inner: itertools::structs::GroupBy<I::Item, I, fn(&I::Item) -> I::Item>,
}

impl<I> Iterator for GroupByCount<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: PartialEq,
{
    type Item = (I::Item, usize);

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.inner
            .into_iter()
            .next()
            .map(|(key, group)| (key, group.count()))
    }
}

pub trait IteratorExt: Iterator {
    fn group_by_count(self) -> GroupByCount<Self>
    where
        Self: Sized;
}

impl<I> IteratorExt for I
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: Clone + PartialEq,
{
    fn group_by_count(self) -> GroupByCount<Self>
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        GroupByCount {
            inner: self.group_by(|i| i.clone()),
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c2c08a421ffd455b66aae6729fd52a1e).

Other improvements I've made:

- Remove redundant `Sized` bounds.
- Remove the now-redundant `'static` bounds.
- Remove the `Eq` bound, as it is unnecessary.
- Get rid of the type parameter `T` and instead explicitly use `I::Item`.
- Rename `ExtIterator` to `IteratorExt`, as per [RFC 445, Extension Trait Conventions](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0445-extension-trait-conventions.html).